# Как изменить кодировку MS SQL BD (asp.net не сохраняет кириллицу)

Tags: sql, asp.net, mvc

при обновлении данных на кирилические в бд -- не сохраняется кириллица:

Пример после обновления данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте тип данных NVARCHAR или NCHAR.